# grunt-newer not working with grunt-sass

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass, gruntjs, libsass

I am trying to use grunt-newer to pick up changes to my sass partials to then run the grunt-sass task. For some reason, it doesn't seem to register any updates. Argh!

Example directory structure:

```
sass
    - components
        _breadcrumb.scss
    - helpers
        _variables.scss
    main.scss
```

Sass config:

```
files: [{
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'static/sass',
    src: ['*.scss'],
    // src: ['**/*.scss'],
    dest: 'static/styles',
    ext: '.css'
}]
```

main.scss contains the @imports used to read in the partials.

Running grunt newer:sass will look for changes to main.scss. Updating the globbing rule to use **/*.scss doesn't pick up any changes at all in any file.

It feels like a globbing issue but I just can't crack it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you run the task?

Comment: I want to run it as part of a concurrent task, part of deployment. For this test though I am simply running it standalone. Updating a scss partial, running newer and going from there

Comment: I believe this may be related to using the expand syntax. See https://github.com/tschaub/grunt-newer/issues/39#issuecomment-91271470

Answer (score 0):

See [grunt-newer page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-newer), specifically the section 'overwrite' at the end of the page. That's the way to go.

```
grunt.config('newer', {
  options: {
    override: function (detail, include) {
      if (detail.task == 'sass') {
        if (detail.path.match('^sass/includes/')) {
          include(true);
        }
        else {
          include(false);
        }
      }
      else {
        include(false);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

(don't forget to adapt and expand `^sass/includes/` to your filetree)

I am not yet 100% sure if this scans ALL files in that folder EVERY time no matter if they are "newer" or not, though...